# Simple way to add parent node

Tags: org-mode

Is there a simple way to add parent node in `org-mode`?

```
* heading
... # 100 or more first-level headings over here
* heading # interspersed with ones with subtrees
** heading
** heading
*** heading
...
```

I would like to add a `NEW HEADING` to the above so that everything else shifts down and right.

```
* NEW HEADING
** heading
*** heading
*** heading
**** heading
...
```

Currently, selecting everything and hitting `M-→` works just some of the time. It gets cumbersome when many sub and/or sub-sub headings are involved.

---

## Note:

I presently use mark set to select region to be demoted. It works only in a specific way and not all the time. Namely, I need to:

1. `C-@ ↓` somewhere above the first `* heading`
2. Move the cursor to the left-most `*` just below the region the be selected
3. Hit `M-→`

Any other method would fail incessantly.

Comment: "Is there a way to..." is not about debugging - that tag is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function inserts a new parent/root node above the current subtree and demotes the original subtree respectively:

```el
(defun org-insert-parent-node ()
  (interactive)
  (catch 'exit
    (while (or (org-up-heading-safe)
               (= (org-outline-level) 1))
      (when (= (org-outline-level) 1)
        (org-insert-heading)
        (save-excursion
          (outline-next-heading)
          (org-demote)
          (throw 'exit t))))))
```

Edit: I reread your question and I think you also want to include first-level headings above the current subtree. With this command you can select the current subtree and any number of first-level headings above it:

```el
(defun org-insert-parent-node (beg end)
  (interactive (list (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (let ((beg (save-excursion
                 (goto-char beg)
                 (skip-chars-forward "* ")
                 (point)))
           (end (save-excursion
                  (goto-char end)
                  (line-beginning-position))))
       (goto-char beg)
       (org-insert-heading)
       (goto-char beg)
       (save-excursion
         (while (outline-next-heading)
           (unless (= end (point))
             (org-demote)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`org-demote-subtree` does that. It is bound to  <kbd>C-c C-></kbd>.

Comment: `C-c C->` works only when there are hidden subtrees under a heading. It is still cumbersome when I have, say 100 first-level headings which I would like to demote in bulk so that they can be bound to a single parent.

Comment: @Sati How should Orgmode know without region which first-level headings you want to demote?

Comment: I presently use mark set (selecting the headings to be demoted) to tell. Works only in small regions. And not all the time. Could this be a bug?

Comment: A workaround would be to use regex find and replace. But it does get complicated when subtrees are involved.

Comment: @Sati You must apply `org-metaright` carefully. Point may not be at a table, a drawer, or a block and either point or mark must be at a heading. (See the function definition for [`org-metaright`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org.el#L17220-L17230).

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, org-mode files are plaintext-based and heading depth is determined by the number of `*` characters in front of it

This means you can simply insert a `*` in front of all headings you want to be demoted in plaintext instead of relying on org-mode functions. You don't even need to exit org-mode for that.

The easiest way to do this I know of is to enter `rectangle-mark-mode` (<kbd>C-x SPC</kbd>) at the beginning of the first line, navigate to the beginning of the last line and use `string-insert-rectangle` (<kbd>C-t</kbd>) to enter as many `*` as levels you want to demote the headings by.
(Evil-mode users can use <kbd>C-v</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> instead.)

**EDIT: This only works if there is no text under headings**

The slightly more complicated way that also works with text under heading is to mark the lines you want to demote and use `replace-regexp` to replace `^*` with `**` and `^SPC` with `SPCSPC`.
(Evil-mode user can use <kbd>C-V</kbd> to mark and `:'<,'>s/^*/**/g` to replace)

Comment: Would this work if there are text under the headings? Wouldn't I be entering the `*` in the middle of the text as well?

Comment: That's true, I didn't have any in my test data, so I didn't notice. You should be able to do a regex search and replace instead though, I'll update my answer.